# script to create a link to a file in a spreadsheet creating error "Cannot Convert"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script searches a spreadsheet and copies the link to the third column according to the value in the first column

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var searchMenuEntries = [ {name: "Search in all files", functionName: "search"}];
  ss.addMenu("Search Document List", searchMenuEntries);
}


function lastValue(column) {
  var lastRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getMaxRows();
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(column + "1:" + column + lastRow).getValues();

  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
  return values[lastRow - 1];
}

function search() {

  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  // Search the files in the user's Docs List for the search term

  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = lastValue("A");   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows)
 // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {

    var files = DocsList.find(data[i].toString());

    for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {


      if (files[j].getType() == "other"){
        urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=";
        sheet.getRange(i, 3, 1, 1).setValue(urlBase + files[j].getId());
       }
    }


  }

}
```

However when I run it, I get the following error:

> Cannot convert d59f868312238f16bd8534f61c01dd0695512d38 in (class)

The string above is the last row value in the column A which I use to retrieve the link (using DocsList.find)

Does anyone knows what is the problem with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Does the error msg include a line number?  If so, please include that in the question, and the code at that line number.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it doesn't show the line where the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DriveApp instead.

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(data[i].toString());

while (files.hasNext()) {

   var file = file.getNext();

   if (file.getMimeType().indexOf("other") !== -1) {
     Logger.log(file.getUrl());
   }
}
```

Comment: Replace "DocsList" with "DriveApp" in that snippet.

Comment: What's the difference between Doclist and DriveApp?  At first time I will think that doclist is related only to google docs and DriveApp is more general, but as Doclist, also brings "other" type, I'm quite confused.

Comment: Dec 11, 2014 - Deprecated. The DocsList service was deprecated on December 11, 2014. To work with files in Google Drive, use the Drive service instead.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, I got an error on this line:

```
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows);
```

You are using the wrong syntax for `getRange()`.  I got an error msg that was similar to yours.

`getRange` can take two types of notation parameters, A1 notation or R1C1 notation.

A1 notation is a string, you have to put it into quotes:

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");
```

R1C1 notation takes four settings.  You have three.  R1C1 notation is:

> Start Row, Start Column, Number of Rows to Get, Number of Columns to Get

It's not explained in the `getRange()` documentation, but you can see an explanation in the `getSheetValues()` documentation here:

[Google Documentation - getSheetValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetValues(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))

Comment: That's good, I didn't know that you can use A1 notation, I think is very useful.  Concerning using just three parameters, it is valid as you can check in my own answer.  You shouldn't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

I refactor the whole program because it has some design flaws.  And I managed to get rid of errors.  However, after running for a while, the script will stop saying that it exceeded the time for running a script.  I put the sleep function, as it was requested by Google, as many requests are made.  However It is not able to finished the 370 rows that I have in my spreadsheet (it stops at 318)

Do you know if there is any way to improve the performance of my algorithm?

```
function search() {


  // Get the active spreadsheet and the active sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


  // Search the files in the user's Docs List for the search term


  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getMaxRows() ;   // Number of rows to process


  //sheet.getRange(2, 3, 1, 1).setValue(numRows.toString());


  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows-1)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  k = startRow
  for (i in data) {
//    sheet.getRange(2, 3, 1).setValue(data[i].toString());
    var files = DocsList.find(data[i].toString()+".txt");
    Utilities.sleep(1000);

    for (var j = 0; j < files.length; j++) {


      if (files[j].getType() == "other"){

        urlBase = "https://docs.google.com/fileview?id=";
        sheet.getRange(k, 8, 1, 1).setValue(urlBase + files[j].getId());
        k = k+1
        break;
      }
     }


  }

}
```